# Fake applications in app store?

Tags: 8.0, apps

What actually do these two applications? They are claiming to improve internet speed.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/2g-net-booster/bfc35021-b9c1-40d8-a03d-2aa4897dc8ea

[image]

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/3g-internet-booster/31b93f5e-65a6-4a81-9551-8a7a3bcb9a42

[image]

Comment: They should be fake since 3rd party developers can't access this level of the phone's API.

Comment: What confuses me is the user reviews! they all say it is great and perfect etc.! how come?

Comment: Spam or placebo effect? Such as the "feels faster" comments on many app updates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are two fine examples of the many scam apps that exist in the Windows Phone Store - other app store have their issues too.

The apps look harmless as they don't ask for permission to resources they don't obviously need eg. Contacts, Pictures, etc.

That said, it's better not to download these too-good-to-be-true apps - simply confirm that they're fake (and do nothing) and report the apps.

As for the many 5 star reviews, it's likely they had some friends help out.

Answer (score 1):

Fake apps are posing a threat to the reliability of app store and security of fellow Windows Phone users. Many of these apps have five-star ratings and luring names. Many of us would have reported such apps already, but reports are either being overlooked or still insufficient in numbers, e.g.these 2G and 3G booster apps are on the app store since a long time now.

Microsoft must consider better policing of the app store!

Answer (score 0):

Sources for positive reviews seem obvious. Not long ago I heard at least one major media news story about paying for positive reviews. I've learned to scan product reviews and try to decipher which ones are legitimate.

Just today I discovered two scam apps (and vendors). Gmail 2014 by iexplore and New Gmail by Apps for Windows Phone. Both try to prevent exit and uninstall.

Comment: If they try to prevent exit, you should report the app to Microsoft; notably, the two apps from the question no longer appear to be available, which implies they were removed from the store for violating the store rules.