# Signal boosting capability of Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: 8.0, signal

I found an interesting app in Windows Phone Store to boost the signal strength of the phone and help to increase network bandwidth too. Does the windows phone has the capability of boosting signal?

Comment: I highly doubt apps get such low-level functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2930/3389

Comment: Those apps are fraudulent. It's not technically possible to do that and never will be.

Comment: @Neil - if the apps are suspected to be fraudulent, then should they be reported to Microsoft in an effort to protect consumers (we are all consumers)?

Comment: @jww yes, of course. But a lot of people must report and app for Microsoft to take notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today `Windows Phone 8 SDK` does not expose any **API** you can manage the way signal is used by the device.

You can find more about what can be done in apps in [What's new in Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Firs thing - Windows phone applications dont have access to Hardware level . They are sandboxed and they cant access much of the hardware component unless they are exposed . 
There are methods to get the signal strength because that API is exposed but there is no way to boost the signal strength !!